# I have a ios project in objective-c i got some errors like PubNub/PubNub.h' file not found and more files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a ios project in objective-c i got some errors like PubNub/PubNub.h' file not found and more files

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "LoadingViewClass.h"
#import <PubNub/PubNub.h>
#import "BaseTabController.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
```

i have this all file but i got this error and i am new in ios development 
thanks for help

Comment: Has this framework been added to your project? You can view the framework of your project links via <Your Target> --> General --> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

Comment: @VincentSit how i get General in xcode

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4aM03qY

Comment: @VincentSit thanks sir

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Remove the PubNub Pod, add it back in and close and reopen the project. This seemed to work for another developer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @CraigConover i got one more problem with design of storybord

Comment: Storyboard should have nothing to do with PubNub so I can't help you there. I suggest posting a new question on Stack Overflow but unless it involves a PubNub API, don't tag it as `pubnub`.